# a width and height 100% and text still at the bottom right - possible?

Tags: html, position, padding, area, tile

I'm creating tiled nav and what I need is for a to fill the tile, but the text from a still be located at bottom right position. However, when I make it width:100% and height:100% (in relation to li), the text jumps to top left of the area. I know why this happens, I think I understand the whole idea, what I don't know is how to force it to jump back to bottom right while still filling the tile.

Here's the code:

```
    #menu {
width: 900px;
float: right;
display: block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}


#menu ul{
list-style:none;
display: block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#menu ul li{
display:inline-block;
width: 146.5px;
height: 146.5px;
background-color: #1BA1E2;
position: relative;
}

#menu ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
display: block;
padding-right:5px;
padding-top:5px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

and the html:

```
      <div id="menu">
           <ul>
                <li><a href="#">pies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">kot</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">czołg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ryba</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">yea</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">umc</a></li>

           </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `li` `display: table-cell` instead of `inline-block;` and use `vertical-align: bottom`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DwtPu/)

```
#menu ul li {
    width: 146.5px;
    height: 146.5px;
    background-color: #1BA1E2;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Note: Your CSS is lil messy so clean up a bit

Comment: @Pete Nice 1 .. You changed it completely, you cleaned up the mess almost, I gave him the idea :)

Comment: I tried that and it is aligned nicely, but a (even in the fiddle above) does not stretch to the tile - it works only on the text. What I need is for the whole tile to be active area.

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek I assume that you want entire block to behave like a link and text to right bottom? see this, you need to change the markup and styles again for that http://jsfiddle.net/DwtPu/1/

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek You welcome :) if this helped, you can mark the answer as correct so that future visitors can refer

Comment: All right, this is silly - I have no idea how to do that :) Could it be my lv is too low for that?

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek hehe no, you need to tick mark the tick below vote up/down arrow on the left side of my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible. (inside the anchor tag you can put `<p>`) and Use following CSS to `<p>`

```
p{

   margin-top:125px;
   float:right;
}
```

Here is the Demo:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79kvs/)

Comment: I tried that and it is aligned nicely, but a (even in the fiddle above) does not stretch to the tile - it works only on the text. What I need is for the whole tile to be active area.